# Make LocalCommand set screen window title only when used interactively?

Tags: bash, ssh, gnu-screen, autocomplete, window-title

#### Setup

I run screen on a local machine and use different screen windows to connect to different hosts. It would be nice to change window names to the host names automatically during the ssh process.

#### Approaches

I have tried different variations of the 2 approaches below:

1) Using `LocalComand` in ssh config file:

```
Host *
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand '[ "${TERM:0:6}" == "screen" ] && printf "\ek@%h\e\\"
```

2) Creating a custom bash function:

```
# function to set screen name based on host and reset on exit
function ssh() {
  echo -e '\033k'@$1'\033\\'
  /usr/bin/env ssh -Y "$@"
  echo -e '\033k'local'\033\\'
}
```

#### Problem

Both of these approaches work but they also seem to interfere with things like auto-completion:

```
$ scp user@host:~/.s<tab>
...o^[\\\\   ...cal^[\\\\
```

#### Question

Is there some condition that could be used (on top of checking if `$TERM == screen`) that would allow executing the `LocalCommand` (or the `ssh()` function) only when connecting to host and not when used for auto-completion?

Comment: The usual thing to do is to set the prompt on the remote machine to output the sequence. This has the added advantage that if you suspend an ssh  and resume it (using `~ ^z` and `fg`) then it continues to provide the correct information.

Comment: @icarus correct me if I am wrong, but this would only change the title of the nested screen session ran within the remote machine? In my case I do not nest screens, just run them locally.